# Typescript does not recognize ant design prop for rendering icon

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I am new in typescript and Ant design. I have a password input and want to have an open/invisible Icon inside input element. But typescript gives me an error, iconRender does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & InputProps & RefAttributes'. How could I fix it?

```
<Input
 type="password"
 className={styles["password-input"]}
 placeholder="Password"
 iconRender={(visible: ReactNode) =>
  visible ? <EyeTwoTone /> : <EyeInvisibleOutlined />
 }
/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `Input.Password` for password input from `antd`. See more: https://ant.design/components/input/#components-input-demo-password-input